# UploadFileAsync not working - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, upload

I'm I'm trying to upload a file to my server via FTP, and it's not working. The Upload complete event is triggered, and there are no exceptions being caught by the try catch block. This should be pretty straightforward right? What am I missing here? I know the web directory is right, because I copied and pasted it right from my browser after navigating to it, and the file that I'm uploading is correct because it makes it past the File.Exists, if statement.

```
        string strWebDirectory = "ftp://sharedhosting.com/mydomain.com/wwwroot/Images/" + txt.Text.Trim();
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("usr", "psw"); 
        wc.UploadFileCompleted += (s, ev) => UploadProgressCompleted();
        if (File.Exists( strStartUpPath + "Upload\\" + txtFile.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(strWebDirectory), strStartUpPath + "Upload\\" + txtFile.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [`Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Probably, there was an error.

Answer (score -1):

You need to await/wait on `UploadFileAsync` to observe the exception it is throwing.

```
            try
            {
                await wc.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(strWebDirectory), strStartUpPath + "Upload\\" + txtFile.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```